# What is the most efficient way to write the following condition

Tags: if-statement, optimization

I have some code that looks like this:

```
if (a == 0 or b == 0) {
    if (c == true) {
        return 0
    else if (a == 0)
        a = 1
        c = true
    else if (b == 0)
        b = 1
        c = true
    }
}
```

What would be the most efficient way to write this code without having to check again for which of a or b is equal to 0? This might have been already answered but I have no idea how would people ask this question.

Comment: What language is this? Add the appropriate language tag. Where is the rest of the code? Why does one branch return and the others don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to condense and remove some unnecessary `if/else` blocks:

```
if ((a == 0 && c == true) || (b == 0 && c == true)) {
  // Since we return here, we don't need the if/else blocks after this
  return 0;
}

if (a == 0) {
  a = 1;
} else if (b == 0) {
  b = 1;
}

// If we reach this point, c is always true regardless of a or b
c = true;
```

But in general, the *efficiency* of the code stay almost unchanged, so you may also want to consider readability as well.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't need the last `if(b == 0)`

```
if (a == 0 or b == 0) {
    if (c == true) {
        return 0
    else if (a == 0)
        a = 1
        c = true
    else
        b = 1
        c = true
    }
}
```